# How to keep multiple marker bubble info open (shown) (HERE Android SDK)

Tags: android, maps, here-api

I'm using HERE Android SDK and I can't seem to make multiple bubble info open. When I click on another marker and show the bubble info, the previous one is closed/hidden. I'd like to keep all the bubble info open if possible or manually close them.
Is there a setting for this or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in infobubble is designed to only show one marker at a time. If you want a custom solution you need to build them on your own, easiest with using the MapOverlay that enables your to put android views on fixed positions on the map:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoverlay.html